# Git Bash crashing for half the office

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, git-bash

This is a bit of a weird problem but I'll try to explain it to the best of my ability. About a month ago, 50% of our dev team started complaining about Git Bash not working for them. Here are some of the issues we are facing:

1. When we try to open Git Bash in VSCode, it crashes and looks like this:
   [image]

   When it should look like this (notice the branch listing on the end of the current directory):
   [image]
2. Upon opening the terminal in VSCode, a bash.exe.stackdump file is created in the repository directory with the following:

   `Stack trace:
   Frame        Function    Args
   000FFFF4FA0  0018005E579 (00000000000, 000FFFFCE00, 000FFFF51A8, 000FFFFDE50)
   00000000002  0018006056A (00000000064, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
   000FFFF5280  00180125C3B (00000000004, 00600072679, 0000000620C, 00000400000)
   000FFFF5C00  0018005E9AD (00180040000, FB1C005E0000, 000FFFF5600, 000FFFF55B0)
   000FFFF5600  7FFC157CED2D (000FFFF5C00, 00180290564, 00000000000, 00000000000)
   000FFFF5600  7FFC15736C86 (000000048D0, 001803209B0, 00003800000, 00000010000)
   000000048D0  7FFC157CDC5E (000FFFF62D0, 00000000002, 000FFFF6480, 000FFFF64A0)
   000000048D0  0018009DEE8 (00000000001, 00000000000, 00600185C90, 00000000000)
   0000000001F  00180144850 (00600185C90, 00100425B20, 00000000002, 000003A0000)
   001005FA650  0018011DE4B (00600185C90, 00100425B20, 00000000002, 000003A0000)
   001005FA650  00100428EFB (00000000003, 00180320C58, 0018013835B, 0010000008B)
   001005FA650  00100429B18 (000000007F0, 00000000000, 001005F57D8, 00000000000)
   00000000001  00100432960 (00100000001, 006001850D0, 00100468FA0, 0010045B140)
   00600185C10  00100437B9A (00000000076, 00000000077, 001800BBA9E, 000FFFF67FC)
   00600185800  00100438BF4 (00000000001, 00100000000, 000FFFF691C, 00000000000)
   00600184BC0  00100439A8C (00100000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
   End of stack trace (more stack frames may be present)`
3. We are unable to run `yarn` in either a Git Bash window or the VSCode terminal.
4. Everything works fine in a plain old Windows Command Line terminal. This is what we have all been using for the past month or so.

We aren't sure what caused this. It happened to some (but not all) workers in our office around the same time (about a month ago). It also occurs on separate repositories.

Things I tried:

- Reinstalling Git for Windows
- Updating Windows